# Why is this RxJava subscription method not invoked?

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2

I am learning RxJava. I subscribed a long-running callback as an observable and was hoping to see the onNext callback executed :

```
fun test(){
    fetchNumber(2,4).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).doOnSubscribe { println("subscribed") }.subscribe({ println(it)})
}

private fun fetchNumber(a: Int, b: Int) : Observable<Int> {
    return Observable.fromCallable {
        Thread.sleep(4000)
        a + b
    }
}
```

I was expecting the output "6" to be printed, but the method finishes before that.

If I don't subscribe on the IO scheduler, then the call is blocked and I do see the output printed.

My question is why is the callback not executed if running on the IO scheduler. I understand that the test() method is terminated, but the reference to subscription callback is not disposed yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RxJava by default uses daemon threads. Your main method ended before the flow had any chance to emit anything. Add some `Thread.sleep()` to the end of `main` or use `blockingSubscribe`.